# Web applications solution for filtering logs in my organization

Tags: linux, database, windows, powershell, server

I need some help on finding a way to manage my log information.

I have 20 windows servers build with application on glassfish which generate logs everyday, so to manage these log in case i need to find something specific from all my servers im trying to group all these data on a single server (windows or linux) and filter them according to my specs.

Best regard Egis

Comment: You can use Elastic Stack:
Filebeat (installed on each glassfish server) -> Logstash (mutate log lines) -> Elasticsearch (store/query logs) -> Kibana (nice front end to filter data and create dashboards from logs stored in Elasticsearch)

Comment: I need a solution for local managment of logs. All server log collected on one server and in case i need to make a specific search on all logs just take a comand on the log server.

Comment: You can use Elastic stack's log analysis solution. check for Splunk or you can search for something else.

Answer (score 0):

It's too broad question but a common solution it's ELK Stack

- elasticsearch - to store the data
- logstash - to process the data, installing it on servers that generate log to send they to elasticsearch server
- kibana - visualize the data

An article explaining the stack solution

https://www.guru99.com/elk-stack-tutorial.html

Comment: In my company we use intranet and every user that access the glassfish aplication make registration about tickets which contain name of a person date and some specifik fields. The aplication generate logs which are stored on glasfish/glasfish3/domain/domain1/logs . In my case i have 20 servers with a load balancer accesed from clients. But all i need is a server to put all the logs inside and every time i have a request to find something,